# Replace fragment in ViewPager, old fragment doesnt remove

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to replace a fragment from a ViewPager and i dont know the best way to do that.

In order to change the fragment i use this code:

```
   Fragment productDetailFragment = RetarFragment.newInstance(null, null);
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.root_frame, productDetailFragment).commit();
```

Where R.id.root_frame is the container of the fragment i will replace and it is a FrameLayout.

The problem is that when i run the app, the fragment runs well but it is over the old fragment, which should be removed.

Any better solution to do that?

The ViewPager's adapter is a
**FragmentStatePagerAdapter**

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter implements Serializable{


    public static final int MENU_RETAR = 2;
    public static final int MENU_BATALLA = 1;
    int MENU_ACTUAL = MENU_BATALLA;

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        switch (position){
            case 0: return new TimelineFragment();
            case 1: return new SearchFragment();
            case 2:

                if(MENU_ACTUAL == MENU_RETAR){
                    return new RetarFragment();
                }else{
                    return new MenuBatallaFragment();
                }

            case 3: return new NotificacionesFragment();
            case 4: return new PerfilFragment().newInstance(this);
            default:
                return new TimelineFragment();
        }
    }



    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {

        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return null;
            case 1:
                return null;
            case 2:
                return null;
            case 3:
                return null;
            case 4:
                return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you meed to add fragments with unique tags. Then whenever you want replace with removing old fragment you need to remove fragment with that unique fragment tag.

Removing fragment ;

```
Fragment fragment =getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG); 

if(fragment != null)   
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
```

Comment: Ok, but... when i remove the fragment?

Comment: If i remove the fragment before replacing it, the resulting fragment is empty

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

If you set in the new fragment's layout a background and clickable="true" it runs right!